# Vectorizing operations in a contained class without breaking class structure

Tags: c#, design-patterns

My current project is split into multiple classes that correctly represent the way we think of the entities in the system. However, this is taking a performance price, so I'm trying to come up with a way of improving performance while maintaining the current class structure we have.

I think an example will best illustrate the problem: Let's say I have an `Order` class that contains multiple `Item`s. A naive implementation for shipping an `Order` is shipping all of its `Item`s:

```
class Order 
{
    private List<Item> m_items;

    public void Ship()
    {
        foreach (Item item in m_items)
        {
            item.Ship();
        }
    }
}
```

Shipping an `Item` is a multi-stage process:

```
class Item
{
    public void Ship()
    {
        var receipt = m_boat.ShipToDestination(this);
        ProcessReceipt(receipt);
    }
}
```

As it turns out, shipping the `Item` on a `Boat` takes a long time. Luckily, the `Boat` can ship multiple `Item`s concurrently (`List<Receipt> Boat.ShipToDestination(List<Item> items)`). However, to use this method I will have to rewrite `Order.Ship()` as follows:

```
class Order 
{
    public void Ship()
    {
        var receipts = m_boat.ShipToDestination(m_items);
        foreach (Receipt receipt in receipts)
        {
            ProcessReceipt(receipt);
        }
    }
}
```

This means that `ProcessReceipt` is now part of `Order` (rather than `Item`), and also that an `Item` no longer takes care of all of its shipping logistics.

In my real code there are many methods with this problem, so using this solution effectively means that most of the `Item` logic will move into the `Order` class. However, this seems like the wrong place to have this logic - it really should be in `Item`.

I considered using multiple threads (e.g. using a `Task` per `Item`) but this seems too wasteful, especially since an `Order` can have dozens of `Items`.

Another approach I considered is creating a `QueuedBoat` with a `QueueForShipping(Item item)` method and a `ShipQueuedItems()` method. Now `Order` can call `ShipQueuedItems` while `Item` can call `QueueForShipping`. The problem with this approach is that in my real code, the `Receipt` is returned only after the `Item` was shipped, so the code would have to look like this:

```
class Order 
{
    private List<Item> m_items;

    public void Ship()
    {
        foreach (Item item in m_items)
        {
            item.Ship();
        }

        m_queuedBoat.ShipQueuedItems();

        foreach (Item item in m_items)
        {
            item.FinalizeShipping();
        }
    }
}


class Item
{
    public void Ship()
    {
        m_queuedBoat.QueueForShipping(this);
    }

    public void FinalizeShipping()
    {
        ProcessReceipt(m_queuedBoat.GetReceiptForItem(this));
    }
}
```

This feels like it's in the right direction (since `Order` knows how many `Item`s it has, it must be the component that knows when everything is on the `Boat`), but it broke `Ship` into two stages. In my real code I have multiple stages (each can be vectorized separately), so the method would be broken into 3-4 pieces, which is not a pretty sight.

Can someone suggest a way of vectorizing `Item.Ship()` while keeping the business logic inside the `Item` class, or will I have to give up on the Order/Item separation in order to take advantage of vectorization?

**Edit:**

Another approach could be this:

```
class Order 
{
    private List<Item> m_items;

    public void Ship()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_items.Count; ++i)
        {
            bool isLast = (i == (m_items.Count - 1));
            item.Ship(isLast);
        }
    }
}

class Item
{
    public void Ship(bool isLast)
    {
        m_queuedBoat.QueueForShipping(this, FinalizeShipping);
        if (isLast) m_queuedBoat.ShipQueuedItems();
    }

    private void FinalizeShipping(Receipt receipt)
    {
        ProcessReceipt(receipt);
    }
}
```

Where the `QueuedBoat` class invokes a callback for each item with its `Receipt`.

Comment: In C#5 it will be easier: one will be able to make `Ship` a `Task<Receipt>` and start it asynchronously with the new async/await technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, anyway `Ship` is a kind of asynchronous operation: there must run several at once. So has to be two-stage: `PrepareShipping` (void) and `PerformShipping` (waits for the actual shipping to finish and <s>returns</s> processes its receipt).

I would so something like that:

```
class Item
{
    public void PrepareShiping()
    {
        m_queuedBoat.QueueForShipping(this);
    }

    public void PerformShipping()
    {
        m_queuedBoat.StartActualShippingIfNotAlreadyStarted();
        m_queuedBoat.WaitForShippingEnd();
        ProcessReceipt(m_queuedBoat.GetReceiptForItem(this));
    }
}
```

So the Order can be something like that:

```
class Order 
{
    public void PrepareShipping()
    {
        foreach (Item item in m_items)
            item.PrepareShiping();
    }

    public void PerformShipping()
    {
        foreach (Item item in m_items)
            item.PerformShipping();
    }

    // and for those who don't need asynchronity
    public void Ship()
    {
        PrepareShipping();
        PerformShipping();
    }
}
```

The program can do additional things while shipping is in progress, that is, between `Order.PrepareShipping()` and `Order.PerformShipping()` (for example, ship out other orders as well, maybe on the same boat).

Comment: (changed names from Begin/End to Prepare/Perform)

Comment: This is an interesting approach. What I like about it is that it doesn't require `Order` to access `QueuedBoat` in order to start the shipping. However, it still requires me to split `Item.Ship` into multiple phases (two phases in the contrived example, three or four phases in my real code). Note that everything is synchronous here: queueing the items for shipping is done one-by-one, then we ship them, then we process the receipts.

Comment: Just realized what you meant by "ship out other orders as well". This is very interesting, as it is actually the next stage of vectorization that we thought of: ship `Item`s from multiple `Order`s on the same `Boat`.

Comment: @telewin: well, you cannot have `Item.Ship` as a single operation, otherwise it would take the whole boat for a single item, because the item doesn't know about other items. There should be a shipping manager who handles this, in my code this is order, which calls first PrepareShipping and only than PerformShipping.

Comment: you're right, of course. I want the first `Item` to queue itself to the `Boat` and then relinquish control until the `Boat` is out. I can't include code in the comment, so please see edit on the original question for a (convoluted?) way of having a single `Ship` method.

Comment: @telewin: well, I would rename `isLast` to `shouldTriggerPerform`, and have it as a parameter of `Order.Ship` too: public void Ship(bool shouldTriggerPerform) { for (int i = 0; i < m_items.Count; ++i) { bool isLast = (i == (m_items.Count - 1)); item.Ship(isLast && shouldTriggerPerform); } }

Comment: After some thinking, I feel it's still a better idea to split shipping in two stages. Imagine that an order is SO big that it's split between two boats. That is, not all items are shipped with the same boat. With your approach we will start actual shipping only on the last boat, right?

Comment: You're certainly right about the name. And adding the same argument to `Order` allow me to vectorize multiple `Order`s, which is great. I'll try this on my actual code to see if it works out.

Comment: Interesting point. Currently, the actual "boat" we're using can handle much more than our largest "order", but I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @telewin: imagine that you process 1000 orders with 2 boats. First 499 orders fit into the 1st boat, and there is still some place. So you might want to place a part of 500th order into the first boat (the whole order doesn't fit). This way the 500th order is split between 2 boats.